# While setting up webpack 4(4.14.0) with Angular 5(5.2.11) getting a run time error on console

Tags: angular5, webpack-4

It seems like pnm packages incompatibility issues, please suggest the appropriate versions of packages
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SlOY.png

Comment: You can check all the incompatibilities through npm cli. Just run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing `@Injectable` annotation on your service. Thus it can't be resolved. So add `@Injectable` to your `SearchTextBoxHttpService`